# Implementing blocking a TCP port

Tags: networking, tcp, port

I've noticed that my employer blocks outgoing traffic on a few problematic ports, such as SSH.    It looks like a timeout to every application being blocked.  Why isn't this implemented by refusing the connection?  Is this simply that the SYN doesn't make it to the destination?  I'm trying to make a list of ports that I am sure are blocked and I'm thinking perhaps I can just port scan a known host outside of the network, such as my VPS.

Are these statements true for most implementations?

- If the connection is refused or accepted, then the port is open
  through the firewall.
- If the connection times out but the host
  certainly exists and doesn't have any kernel-level features turned on
  to make it look like it doesn't exist, then the firewall is blocking
  it.

Comment: Different firewalls block traffic in different ways, so you cannot reliably differentiate between a firewall blockage and a real network error.

Comment: Questions on **professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your firewall may block/allow depending on IP address as well, so the port alone doesn't say anything.

If the connection is accepted, it doesn't mean the firewall isn't blocking, it might just mean the firewall redirects it elsewhere. For example, redirect all traffic to port 80 outside your organization to some "you can't get there from here" webpage.

If the connection times out, it may have lots of reasons, one of them being the firewall, but it might also be your DSL line is down, or routing is misconfigured somewhere, or just about anything that can go wrong on the network.

Even if the connection is accepted AND connects the correct target (your VPS), it might have been redirected to a transparent proxy.

Think twice about the port scan. If the network people of your company manage their network well, they will detect the port scan, and you'll have to answer some embarrasing questions to them.

Comment: Good points about IP-dependent rules and misleading accepts

Answer (score 0):

It's a security consideration. Sending a reset (refusing the connection) indicates that the resource exists, which is itself an information leak. Sending nothing reveals nothing, leaks nothing: it is indistinguishable from the case where the entire host doesn't exist. There was one firewall product in the 1990s that sent resets, which was considered poor practice.

I'm away from my library at the moment but I'll provide more details on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

You can profile what outbound ports are blocked with Firebind.

Check out [scanme.firebind.com](http://scanme.firebind.com)

It uses a custom client/server solution to specifically enumerate firewall rules.

Dave